# ESLint and/or Prettier plugin that will format javascript and JSX arguments on new lines.

Tags: gratis, react, lint, formatter

I'm looking for an ESLint or Prettier plugin that is going to format my React code in the following way:

**Javascript**

Single, or double function calls, and function declarations are on single lines, three or more arguments format on separate lines.

eg.

```
function foo(alpha, beta) {
   //
}

foo("biz", 'baz"); 

function bar(
   alpha, 
   beta, 
   charlie
){
    //
}

bar(
 "a", 
 "b", 
 "c"
);
```

**JSX**

All tags format arguments on new lines:

```
<MyComponent
    foo = {foo}
    bar = "bar" 
    classes = {{
      foo: classes.foo
      innerObj: {
         biz: "bash"
      }
    }}
/>
```

Is there an existing ESLint or Prettier plugin that will give me this kind of formatting?